# How to add filtering pop up in Acumatica

Tags: erp, acumatica

At CT502000 screen in Acumatica I noticed filterable pop up which filters data. How to add similar filter to my grid? Please don't confuse them with PXDialog pop ups.

Comment: Please provide some context for your question or make it more specific.  It's hard to tell what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you need PXFilteredProcessing attribute. For example in my project I did the following:

```
[PXFilterable]
public PXSelectReadonly<AnticipatedPayrollDetail> AnticipatedPayrollDetails;
```

This code caused apperance of the following filter:
[image]